# Filter options displayed on another page

Tags: excel, vba, search, filtering, path-finding

I am looking to use Excel to generate reports using a database I have already built. I am wondering if it is possible to be able to filter my data and have my filter options show up on a separate page. This way it can all be done from a control board and no one has to deal with the DB directly. Is this possible?

I have figured out how to get the data to path from Excel to the doc template but I am getting stuck trying to filter my data and have it sent. Ideally, I would like to have it be able to be passed from the DB in one click of a button.

Can anyone provide insight to this?

Comment: This question lacks the detail needed to offer much help.  **1)** What is the database?  **2)** Where do you want the filter to run (on the DB or via Excel)? **3)** What have you tried so far?  A little bit of code and a picture goes a long way to seeing what you are struggling with.  Beyond those details, the most I can say is "Yes", you can probably do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I am using excel as a database to keep track of real estate properties. I am leaving after the summer and would like to leave a nice DB for future employees to use. Therefore, I would like for people to avoid seeing the actual DB if they can avoid it, it sometimes causes confusion. 

Ideally, I would like to be able to select the criteria to filter data against on a separate home page without ever having to use any computer skills greater than using labelled drop down lists. I have tried using advanced filter but it hasn't worked. 

Does this clarify things for you?

Comment: It is a start, but saying `advanced filter hasn't worked` does not give us much to help.  The `Advanced Filter` would be my first choice here.  So _why_ did not work?  _What_ did it not do?  [Update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30540140/edit) with a sufficient level of detail that a complete outsider (like all of us) can understand your specific problem.  Relevant: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [rubber duck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.